# Unable to perform any operation on real device using appium for native app automation

Tags: java, appium

I am trying to use Appium for testing calculator app (Just for knowledge purpose). But I am not able to perform any operation. Below is the details: 
Real Mobile: Xiaomi Redmi Note 3 
Android version: 6.0.1 
MIUI: 8.1 
Appium version: 1.4.16 
Android SDK version: 24.4.1 
appium java-client: 4.1.2 
Code:

```
package unittest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class LaunchWardRobe {

    @Test
    public void swipeTest() throws IOException {
        String propFileName = "wardrobe.properties";
        InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(inputStream);
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, prop.getProperty("cap.platform.version"));
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, prop.getProperty("cap.platform.name"));
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, prop.getProperty("cap.device.name"));
        cap.setCapability("appPackage", prop.getProperty("cap.app.package"));
        cap.setCapability("appActivity", prop.getProperty("cap.app.activity"));
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "Appium");
        AndroidDriver<MobileElement> browser = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(
                new URL(prop.getProperty("cap.hub.url")), cap);
        MobileElement dig5 = browser.findElement(By.id("com.miui.calculator:id/btn_5"));
        dig5.tap(1, 3);
        dig5.click();
        browser.closeApp();
    }
}
```

Properties File:

```
cap.platform.version=6.0.1
cap.platform.name=Android
cap.device.name=Redmi
cap.app.package=com.miui.calculator
cap.app.activity=com.miui.calculator.cal.CalculatorActivity
cap.hub.url=http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub
```

Exception or stacktrace on the Eclipse Console IDE:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 410 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
System info: host: 'mrunal-laptop', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities [{appPackage=com.miui.calculator, networkConnectionEnabled=true, warnings={}, databaseEnabled=false, deviceName=80b83390, platform=LINUX, appActivity=com.miui.calculator.cal.CalculatorActivity, desired={appPackage=com.miui.calculator, appActivity=com.miui.calculator.cal.CalculatorActivity, platformVersion=6.0.1, automationName=Appium, browserName=, platformName=Android, deviceName=Redmi}, platformVersion=6.0.1, webStorageEnabled=false, locationContextEnabled=false, automationName=Appium, browserName=, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=Android}]
Session ID: caa419ad-6146-47e0-a1b1-ef700d6645e6
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:40)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.performTouchAction(AppiumDriver.java:336)
    at io.appium.java_client.MultiTouchAction.perform(MultiTouchAction.java:71)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.tap(AppiumDriver.java:361)
    at io.appium.java_client.MobileElement.tap(MobileElement.java:50)
    at unittest.LaunchWardRobe.swipeTest(LaunchWardRobe.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Appium Logs:

```
info: [debug] Appium session started with sessionId caa419ad-6146-47e0-a1b1-ef700d6645e6 info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 303 10720.889 ms - 74  info: --> GET /wd/hub/session/caa419ad-6146-47e0-a1b1-ef700d6645e6 {} info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"platform":"LINUX","browserName":"","platformVersion":"6.0.1","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"appPackage":"com.miui.calculator","appActivity":"com.miui.calculator.cal.CalculatorActivity","platformVersion":"6.0.1","automationName":"Appium","browserName":"","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"Redmi"},"appPackage":"com.miui.calculator","appActivity":"com.miui.calculator.cal.CalculatorActivity","automationName":"Appium","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"80b83390"},"sessionId":"caa419ad-6146-47e0-a1b1-ef700d6645e6"} info: <-- GET /wd/hub/session/caa419ad-6146-47e0-a1b1-ef700d6645e6 200 1.228 ms - 700 {"status":0,"value":{"platform":"LINUX","browserName":"","platformVersion":"6.0.1","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"appPackage":"com.miui.calculator","appActivity":"com.miui.calculator.cal.CalculatorActivity","platformVersion":"6.0.1","automationName":"Appium","browserName":"","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"Redmi"},"appPackage":"com.miui.calculator","appActivity":"com.miui.calculator.cal.CalculatorActivity","automationName":"Appium","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"80b83390"},"sessionId":"caa419ad-6146-47e0-a1b1-ef700d6645e6"} info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/caa419ad-6146-47e0-a1b1-ef700d6645e6/element {"using":"id","value":"com.miui.calculator:id/btn_5"} info: [debug] Waiting up to 0ms for condition info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.miui.calculator:id/btn_5","context":"","multiple":false}] info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.miui.calculator:id/btn_5","context":"","multiple":false}} info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: find info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding com.miui.calculator:id/btn_5 using ID with the contextId:  multiple: false info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.miui.calculator:id/btn_5] info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"1"}} info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"1"},"sessionId":"caa419ad-6146-47e0-a1b1-ef700d6645e6"} info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/caa419ad-6146-47e0-a1b1-ef700d6645e6/element 200 82.020 ms - 87 {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"1"},"sessionId":"caa419ad-6146-47e0-a1b1-ef700d6645e6"} info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/caa419ad-6146-47e0-a1b1-ef700d6645e6/touch/perform {"actions":[{"action":"press","options":{"element":"1"}},{"action":"wait","options":{"ms":3}},{"action":"release","options":{}}]} info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:getLocation",{"elementId":"1"}] info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:getSize",{"elementId":"1"}] info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:getLocation","params":{"elementId":"1"}} info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: getLocation info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":{"x":270,"y":1317}} info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:getSize","params":{"elementId":"1"}} info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: getSize info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":{"width":270,"height":201}} info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:getLocation",{"elementId":"1"}] info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:getLocation","params":{"elementId":"1"}} info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: getLocation info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:getSize",{"elementId":"1"}] info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":{"x":270,"y":1317}} info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:getSize","params":{"elementId":"1"}} info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: getSize info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":{"width":270,"height":201}} info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:touchDown",{"elementId":"1","x":405,"y":1417.5}] info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:touchDown","params":{"elementId":"1","x":405,"y":1417.5}} info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: touchDown info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Performing TouchDown using element? true x: 405, y: 1417 info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [error] error while invoking method private boolean com.android.uiautomator.core.InteractionController.touchDown(int,int) on object com.android.uiautomator.core.InteractionController@358f4be with parameters [405, 1417] null info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Problem invoking touchDown: java.lang.RuntimeException: error while invoking method private boolean com.android.uiautomator.core.InteractionController.touchDown(int,int) on object com.android.uiautomator.core.InteractionController@358f4be with parameters [405, 1417] info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":13,"value":{"message":"An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.","origValue":"Failed to execute touch event"},"sessionId":"caa419ad-6146-47e0-a1b1-ef700d6645e6"} info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/caa419ad-6146-47e0-a1b1-ef700d6645e6/touch/perform 500 358.523 ms - 198  info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":13,"value":"Failed to execute touch event"}
```

Answer (score 6):

I too encountered the same problem and found the solution, Redmi note 3 has an extra level of security in the developer options only after enabling that will the actions then work, i tried and is working for me. Try:

1. Go to developer options
2. Here, below usb Debugging(Which you have already enabled) you will find another option 'USB Debugging (Security Settings)'
3. Enable this, it will throw few warning pop ups, keep allowing and it will then be enabled, now all actions can be performed. You can disable this once your testing is done.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work.
 `static AndroidDriver<WebElement> ds; 
 File appDir = new File("Folder_Path");

 File app = new File(appDir,"App_Name");

 DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

 capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","device_name");

 capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "device_version");

 capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());

 capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "package_name");

 capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "app_Activity");

 capabilities.setCapability("noReset","true");

 ds = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);`

Do your operation.

Comment: Ok..well it seems Xiaomi Redmi Note 3 sucks (Big Time)..I tried my stuff onto samsung mobile as is and it worked, would you know if we need to do anything special for Xiaomi phones. NOTE: I was able to launch native application with my code but not able to perform any operation on it

Comment: May be the problem with the MIUI I guess

Comment: @Mrunal Gosar same issues i have facing with redmi note 3.

Answer (score 0):

Just turn on "Install via USB" options. it works on me

Answer (score 0):

The **only solution** worked for me is as follows:

1. **Install** [appium settings apk](https://github.com/appium/io.appium.settings/releases/tag/v5.0.5) manually on my device
2. Go to settings and **allow** all **permissions** for appium settings app
3. **Keep** the app open than **run** the testing scripts and that solved the problem successfully.

Good luck.